# Invalid RegEx in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, cors

I have a code for CORS configuration in NodeJS. It is as follows:

```
var allowedOrigin = new RegExp('^https?://(' + config.get('http:allowedOrigins').join('|') + ')(:\\d+)?(/.*)?$');
```

It gives this error to

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^https?://(*.dev.examplewebsite.com|0.0.0.0|192.168.1.1|.*)(:\d+)?(/.*)?$/: Nothing to repeat
    at new RegExp (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yagiz/Desktop/example/project-api/src/lib/handlers/cors.js:4:21)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a RegExp.escape function in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript)

Comment: I answered the asked question but I don't see how you could use such a regular exception. You probably need more sanitation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you need to escape the special characters (for example the dot) in the string you concatenate.

Find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) a function to escape a string for a regular expression:

```
RegExp.escape= function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};

var allowedOrigin = new RegExp(
    '^https?://(' +
    config.get('http:allowedOrigins').map(RegExp.escape).join('|') +
    ')(:\\d+)?(/.*)?$'
);
```